# Get the information of the class which requests for the bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Considering the following classes:

```
class A
{
    @Inject
    private B b;
}

class B
{

}

@Configuration
class SomeConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public B b()
    {
        // Is there a way to get the information of the class that requests for this bean within this body of the bean definition method?
        // Ie. the class name of the requesting class 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access the requesting class's information within the body of the bean definition method?

Comment: Why would you need that information?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm trying to create a bean for a logger that has special logic, but the init of the logger needs the class from which the logs will be emitted.

Comment: What class? There could be hundreds of *beans* wanting to be injected with a `B` object. At the time the method is called, the Spring container only knows of one of them. To answer your question: **No**, it is not possible.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry I wasn't clear about the question, the bean is of prototype scope not the default singleton scope. So for a prototype bean, it will only be created whenever some class is requesting it? So Spring IOC should know something about the requesting class right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` is a Logger, that needs to know about `A`, then you should use a Factory Pattern, similar to how all logging frameworks work.

Logging frameworks usually has a single global factory. With Spring, you should get such a factory injected.

Example:

```
interface Logger {
    void log(String message);
}

interface LoggerFactory {
    Logger getLogger(Object context);
}

@Component
class MyLoggerFactory implements LoggerFactory {
    @Override
    public Logger getLogger(Object context) {
        return new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                System.out.println(context.getClass().getSimpleName() +
                                   " says '" + message + "'");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Component
class A {
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    public void setLogger(LoggerFactory factory) {
        this.logger = factory.getLogger(this);
    }
}
```